# How can I wrap strings while printing?

Tags: c#, printing, word-wrap

I want to wrap those numbers into two line to fit into the column. currently drawing with

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(
        ViewA.Rows[sn].Cells["itemcode"].Value.ToString(), 
        font, 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new PointF(e.MarginBounds.Left, un));
```

Can we make those strings wrap from 10. char when those `string.length > 10`?
 e.g.       33435356985968  will be

```
                                            3343535698
                                                  5968
```

[image]

Edit : I change code to this. Thanks to Henk Holterman I use rectangleF. Is there anything to improve this?

```
                       string texts;
                      string measureString = "123456";
                       Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 18);
                      SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
                      stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

           for (; sinirr <ViewA.RowCount ; sinirr++)

                   {
                 if (ustsin + yuk > e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                   {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
                    }             
              if (ViewA.Rows[sinirr].Cells["itemcode"].Value.ToString().Length > 10)
                 {                                    
                texts = ViewA.Rows[sinirr].Cells["itemcode"].Value.ToString();
                graphics.DrawString(texts, font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new PointF(e.MarginBounds.Left, ustsin),stringSize));
                ustsin += 2* yuk;
                  }
```

Comment: No on chars but there is an overload of DrawString() that accepts a Rect.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks, I updated the question.